# How to use setSupportActionBar function in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, toolbar

I've created toolbar in xml layout. Then I've initialized it in java with the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar);
}}
```

As you can see in the code above I tried to `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar);`, but I got an error. Also I've tried write it as  `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` and both didn't work. 
What is way to use this function correctly? Which arguments should I put here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've found an answer. If you have the same problem, then you should put `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` instead of `import android.v7.Toolbar;`

Comment: Support libraries? Check the androidx migration